# Simple Node.js server not able to handle few hundred concurrent requests

Tags: performance, node.js, sockets, network-programming

I am using [Hello world](https://github.com/creationix/node-router) example like this-

```
var sys = require("sys"),
my_http = require("http");
my_http.createServer(function(request,response){

        response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
        response.writeHeader(200,{"Connection":"Keep-Alive"});
        response.write("Hello World");
        response.end();
}).listen(8080);
sys.puts("Server Running on 8080");
```

On the client side, I'm using ab as follow- (total of 100000 requests using 5k concurrent connections)

```
ab -n 100000 -c 5000 http://192.168.0.99:8080/
```

When I do  `netstat -antp | grep 8080 | grep ESTABLISHED |wc -l` I only get value ranging from 200 to 300. On the server side, same command shows only 10-20 concurrent connections.

First, why there is a difference in two numbers? Shouldn't both be same?

Secondly, why I am not seeing 1000s of ESTABLISHED connections?

Server side config- http://pastebin.com/Cc77YQp7

Client side config - http://pastebin.com/4pV16TuD

As you can see, I've set TIME_WAIT to expire in 1 second and also optimized other parameters (increasing ulimit etc) after Googling but I can't find the root cause of these two issues.

In fact, many a times I get error- `apr_socket_recv: Connection timed out (110)` on client side (in ab tool)

Client is running on Ubuntu 12 LTS and Node.JS is running on Debian stable (wheezy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to increase the value for socket pooling. Try:

my_http.globalAgent.maxSockets = Infinity // or some reasonable number...